# What to do to dubug/execute an existing PHP project

Tags: php

I am beginner to PHP. I want to debug/execute an existing PHP project. I have already installed Eclipse as IDE and what else should be installed  in my system (OS is Windows xp).
And what and all settings should do in that...??

I request you to invest few seconds for this "Kid of PHP".......

Comment: install a debugger like xdebug.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend installing [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), it allows you to run a website on your local machine.

Comment: I have installed XAMP... It contains 2 folders called "mysql" and "tmp". My Question is, where exactly I should keep the existing project(code).

Comment: There should also be a folder named "htdocs", this is where your files go. You should also make sure that your xamp service (apache & mysql) are running. You can check this by going to: http://localhost/ in your browser.

Comment: "htdocs" is not there under the XAMP directory. And to check running status I tried as "'http://www.'localhost/xamp". is this the way...?

Comment: If I remember correctly, XAMP installs to c:/ (root) so you should have c:/xamp/htdocs/ - does that not exist? Does http://localhost/ load for you or does it give you an error message?

Comment: Ya you are right, its C:\xampp only, but under this i have only 2 directories, namely mysql and tmp. And the localhost giving the error as Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage (in IE).

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've fully installed XAMP, try re-installing it.

Comment: After uninstalling XAMP also PHP 5.3.5 is there in the "Add and remove programs". Is it ok or should i uninstall it also...

Comment: It doesn't matter, just go through the installer again and make sure you install mysql, apache and PHP.

Comment: Yes Prisoner, you are right...Thanks, I got htdocs directory.. But it contains many folders and files, which are 'forbidden', xampp, restricted.. and files favicon.ico,  index.html, index.php apache_pb.png and so on... What the use of them....? shall i delete them..?

Answer (score 0):

php and a web server would come in handy ;-)

http://windows.php.net/download/
http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi

Answer (score 0):

Firephp is a Firefox extension. It works as a module of Firebug. After you install it and add the php library to your code your messages will appear inside the browser. A real quick and clear way to debug in php.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are a beginner, it is better NOT to go after advanced debuggers like xDebug at the moment.

```
print_r(); die;
```

is the best debugging tool for you now.
Also if you want to nicely format the output of `print_r()` when arrays or objects are shown, do this:-

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($array), '</pre>';
```

And Eclipse! If you are a beginner (or pro), definitely go for [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/index.html). NetBeans comes with built-in support for xDebug and zend debugger and a lot other cool stuff you can use when you learn more. If you are going with Eclipse, you will need to install Eclipse extensions like PDT for making Eclipse support PHP.

Of course you will need a web server with PHP support. If you already don't have that, install [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) as somebody mentioned earlier. That's the easy way to get the web server running quickly.

NetBeans is just great, everything works out of the box. Very little to configure. (I'm a former Eclipse user)